# How to make a shallow copy of a list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to implement an algorithm in Python to generate all Permutations of a list. But I In my for loop I wish to keep the original prefix and rest lists intact, and therefore I am trying to make a copy of those lists using newprefix and newrest, however on printing the variable rest at each iteration, I see that even the variable rest is getting modified! How can I make a shallow copy of the list in Python? Or is there another issue with my attempted logic?

```
def perm(prefix, rest):
    if len(rest) == 0:
        print prefix 
    for i in range(len(rest)):
        #prints in the for loop are just for debugging
        print "rest:", rest
        print "i=", i
        newprefix = prefix
        newprefix.append(rest[i])
        newrest = rest
        newrest.pop(i)
        print "old pre : ", prefix
        print "newpre=", newprefix
        print "newrest=", newrest
        perm(newprefix, newrest)


perm([], ['a','b','c'])
```

Comment: Unless this is for your own enrichment, you probably should use itertools.permutations().

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To make a shallow copy, you can slice the list:

```
newprefix = prefix[:]
```

Or pass it into the `list` constructor:

```
newprefix = list(prefix)
```

Also, I think you can simplify your code a little:

```
def perm(prefix, rest):
    print prefix, rest

    for i in range(len(rest)):
        perm(prefix + [rest[i]], rest[:i] + rest[i + 1:])

perm([], ['a','b','c'])
```

Comment: Your first one (slicing) is my preferred way of accomplishing this.  I just thought I'd let them know about the copy module as well.  +1

Comment: Just wondering - isn't the slice operation non-declarative? Isn't it best to clearly declare what you're doing? `copied_list = original_list[:]` doesn't declare that a copy is occurring, whereas `copied_list = copy.copy(original_list)` is highly declarative.

Comment: @user11580406 this is incorrect. A simple test at the Python command line will prove that `list(original)` will create a shallow copy of `original`

Comment: If `s` is a string, why does `s[:]` produce an object with the same memory address as `s` according to [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-May/079694.html). In other words, `s is s[:]` if `s` is a string, but if `s` is an array, `s is not s[:]`

Answer (score 20):

```
import copy

a = [somestuff]
b = copy.copy(a) # Shallow copy here.
c = copy.deepcopy(a) # Deep copy here.
```

The copy module is worth knowing about.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

(Python 2) http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html