# How to deep copy a list?

Tags: python, list, copy, deep-copy

After `E0_copy = list(E0)`, I guess `E0_copy` is a deep copy of `E0` since `id(E0)` is not equal to `id(E0_copy)`. Then I modify `E0_copy` in the loop, but why is `E0` not the same after?

```
E0 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
for k in range(3):
    E0_copy = list(E0)
    E0_copy[k][k] = 0
    #print(E0_copy)
print E0  # -> [[0, 2, 3], [4, 0, 6], [7, 8, 0]]
```

Comment: Also, b = a[:] is a shallow copy. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270374/how-to-make-a-shallow-copy-of-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 391, accepted):

`E0_copy` is not a deep copy. You don't make a deep copy using `list()`. (Both `list(...)` and `testList[:]` are shallow copies, as well as `testList.copy()`.)

You use [`copy.deepcopy(...)`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) for deep copying a list.

> `copy.deepcopy(x[, memo])`
>
> Return a deep copy of *x*.

See the following snippet -

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b = list(a)
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> a[0][1] = 10
>>> a
[[1, 10, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b   # b changes too -> Not a deepcopy.
[[1, 10, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Now see the `deepcopy` operation

```
>>> import copy
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> a
[[1, 10, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 10, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> a[0][1] = 9
>>> a
[[1, 9, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b    # b doesn't change -> Deep Copy
[[1, 10, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

To explain, `list(...)` does not recursively make copies of the inner objects. It only makes a copy of the outermost list, while still referencing the same inner lists, hence, when you mutate the inner lists, the change is reflected in both the original list and the shallow copy. You can see that shallow copying references the inner lists by checking that `id(a[0]) == id(b[0])` where `b = list(a)`.

Comment: list1.append(list2) is also a shallow copy of list2

Comment: Keep in mind that `copy.deepcopy` is [incredibly slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62865237/6243352) relative to list slicing (about 20x). [Implementing `__deepcopy__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15774013/6243352) in a class can help speed it up a bit.

Comment: @Lazik Eh? No it's not. Where did you get that from? Maybe you meant something like `list1 = []; list1.extend(list2)`?

Comment: I meant list1[0] will be a shallow copy of list2. You can check with id(list1[0])

Comment: @Lazik No, it's not a copy. To prove it, `list1 = []; list2 = [99]; list1.append(list2); list1[0] is list2` -> `True`.

Comment: @wjandrea "A shallow copy of an object is a copy whose properties share the same references (point to the same underlying values) as those of the source object from which the copy was made." -mozilla

Comment: @Lazik But it's not a copy in the first place

Comment: @wjandrea It's called a shallow copy of list2 in list1. you can have a look at watashiSHUN's answer.

Answer (score 99):

In Python, there is a module called `copy` with two useful functions:

```
import copy
copy.copy()
copy.deepcopy()
```

`copy()` is a shallow copy function. If the given argument is a compound data structure, for instance a **list**, then Python will create another object of the same type (in this case, a **new list**) but for everything inside the old list, only their reference is copied. Think of it like:

```
newList = [elem for elem in oldlist]
```

Intuitively, we could assume that `deepcopy()` would follow the same paradigm, and the only difference is that for each **elem we will recursively call deepcopy**, (just like [mbguy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17874465/4518341))

***but this is wrong!***

`deepcopy()` actually preserves the graphical structure of the original compound data:

```
a = [1,2]
b = [a,a] # there's only 1 object a
c = deepcopy(b)

# check the result
c[0] is a # False, a new object a_1 is created
c[0] is c[1] # True, c is [a_1, a_1] not [a_1, a_2]
```

This is the tricky part: during the process of `deepcopy()`, a hashtable (dictionary in Python) is used to map each old object ref onto each new object ref, which prevents unnecessary duplicates and thus preserves the structure of the copied compound data.

[Official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

Comment: The deepcopy docs should be updated to prominently include the warning/example at the end of this answer.

Comment: It has to work this way to be general-purpose, because otherwise it would get into an unbound loop or recursion trying to process a cycle.

Answer (score 26):

If the contents of the list are primitive data types, you can use a comprehension

```
new_list = [i for i in old_list]
```

You can nest it for multidimensional lists like:

```
new_grid = [[i for i in row] for row in grid]
```

Comment: This is not a deep copy.

Comment: It is not a deep copy, but manually applying shallow copies to a specified "depth" is often sufficient to solve the underlying problem.

Answer (score 14):

@Sukrit Kalra

No.1: `list()`, `[:]`, `copy.copy()` are all shallow copy. If an object is compound, they are all not suitable. You need to use `copy.deepcopy()`.

No.2: `b = a` directly, `a` and `b` have the same reference, changing `a` is even as changing `b`.

## set a to b

if assgin `a` to `b` directly, `a` and `b` share one reference.

```py
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b = a
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> a[0] = 1
>>> a
[1, [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[1, [4, 5, 6]]


>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b = a
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> a[0][1] = 10
>>> a
[[1, 10, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 10, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

## shadow copy

### by `list()`

`list()` and `[:]` are the same. Except for the first layer changes, all other layers' changes will be transferred.

```py
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b = list(a)
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> a[0] = 1
>>> a
[1, [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]


>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b = list(a)
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> a[0][1] = 10
>>> a
[[1, 10, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 10, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

### by `[:]`

```py
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> a[0] = 1
>>> a
[1, [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]


>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> a[0][1] = 10
>>> a
[[1, 10, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 10, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

### list() and [:] change the other layers, except for the 1st layer

```py
# =========== [:] ===========
>>> a = [[1, 2, [3.5, 6]], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> a
[[1, 2, [3.5, 6]], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, [3.5, 6]], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> a[0][2] = 4
>>> a
[[1, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6]]


>>> a = [[1, 2, [3.5, 6]], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b = a[:]
>>> a
[[1, 2, [3.5, 6]], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, [3.5, 6]], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> a[0][2][0] = 999
>>> a
[[1, 2, [999, 6]], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, [999, 6]], [4, 5, 6]]



# =========== list() ===========
>>> a = [[1, 2, [3.5, 6]], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b = list(a)
>>> a
[[1, 2, [3.5, 6]], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, [3.5, 6]], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> a[0][2] = 4
>>> a
[[1, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6]]


>>> a = [[1, 2, [3.5, 6]], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b = list(a)
>>> a
[[1, 2, [3.5, 6]], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, [3.5, 6]], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> a[0][2][0] = 999
>>> a
[[1, 2, [999, 6]], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, [999, 6]], [4, 5, 6]]
```

### by `copy()`

You will find that `copy()` function is the same as `list()` and `[:]`. They are all **shallow copy**.

For much more information about shallow copy and deep copy, maybe you can reference [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).

```py
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b = copy.copy(a)
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> a[0][1] = 10
>>> a
[[1, 10, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 10, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

## by `deepcopy()`

```py
>>> import copy
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> a[0] = 1
>>> a
[1, [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]


>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> a[0][1] = 10
>>> a
[[1, 10, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include  an explanation of how this works and why it is of solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer].

Comment: [Here is the much more detailed case](https://blog.caoyu.info/copy-list-python.html)

Answer (score 8):

If your list elements are **immutable objects** then you can use this, otherwise you have to use `deepcopy` from `copy` module.

you can also use shortest way for deep copy a `list` like this.

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = a[:] #deep copying the list a and assigning it to b
print id(a)
20983280
print id(b)
12967208

a[2] = 20
print a
[0, 1, 20, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10]
print b
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10]
```

Comment: This is not a Deep Copy.

Comment: Then what is it. It has two different dictionaries (you can check the id's of each one) with same values.

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html), [:] just creates a shallow copy, it does not recursively create copies of the objects inside one.

Comment: Thanks. you mean to say if we use this, new list will be created but all elements of new list will be copies only, they will be having same object (same id) as of previous one ?

Comment: Try using a nested list. Update the nested item of the list a. It'll get updated in list b too. This implies a[:] isn't deep copy.

Comment: [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html) (see `list.copy()`) explicitly describes `a[:]` as a way to perform a shallow copy.

Comment: This solutions works only when we don't have nested lists, in case of nested list, it will be a shallow copy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to deep copy a 2D list:

```
  b = [x[:] for x in a]
```

Comment: Did you test this example?   `a = [3, 4, 5]    b = [x[:] for x in a]    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Ah, I wrote that for 2D lists. a = [[0,1],[2,3]]. I've edited the answer to highlight this.

Comment: @AnupamChugh, this is not a deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to directly import modules you can define your own deepcopy function as -

```
def copyList(L):
if type(L[0]) != list:
    return [i for i in L]
else:
    return [copyList(L[i]) for i in range(len(L))]
```

It's working can be seen easily as -

```
>>> x = [[1,2,3],[3,4]]
>>> z = copyList(x)
>>> x
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4]]
>>> z
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4]]
>>> id(x)
2095053718720
>>> id(z)
2095053718528
>>> id(x[0])
2095058990144
>>> id(z[0])
2095058992192
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are assigning to the same list using deepcopy,
use a temporary variable instead. For some reason, copy.deepcopy() does not work on object lists when trying to self update same variable using indexing

```
S = S[idx] ->x
S = copy.deepcopy(S[idx])  -> x
```

vvvv although this worked

```
Stemp = np.zeros(N,dtype=object)
for ii in range(N):
   Stemp[ii]=copy.deepcopy(S[idx[ii]])
S= copy.deepcopy(Stemp)
```

Answer (score -1):

just a recursive deep copy function.

```
def deepcopy(A):
    rt = []
    for elem in A:
        if isinstance(elem,list):
            rt.append(deepcopy(elem))
        else:
            rt.append(elem)
    return rt
```

Edit: As Cfreak mentioned, this is already implemented in `copy` module.

Comment: There's no reason to reimplement the standard `deepcopy()` function in the `copy` module

Answer (score -1):

Regarding the list as a tree, the deep_copy in python can be most compactly written as

```py
def deep_copy(x):
    if not isinstance(x, list):
        return x
    else:
        return [deep_copy(elem) for elem in x]
```

It's basically recursively traversing the list in a depth-first way.