# Python copying or cloning a defaultdict variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, copy, defaultdict

How can I make a duplicate copy (not just assigning a new pointer to the same location in memory) of Python's defaultdict object?

```
from collections import defaultdict
itemsChosen = defaultdict(list)    
itemsChosen[1].append(1)
dupChosen = itemsChosen
itemsChosen[2].append(1)
print dupChosen
```

What the code above does is a shallow copy and returns

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [1], 2: [1]})
```

whereas what I'm looking for it to return

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [1]})
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's not even a shallow copy, that's just two references to the same object.  A shallow copy would be `itemsChosen.copy()`.

Comment: also as an aside... `defaultdict`, like many built-ins, has a copy function: `dupChosen = itemsChosen.copy()`...

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications- I misunderstood shallow/deep copying. I also couldn't a page of functions for defaultdict, but that makes sense since it inherits from dict.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [copy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html):

```
from copy import copy

dupChosen = copy(itemsChosen)
```

In case of multiple nestings there is also deepcopy.

Comment: How Pythonic! I'll accept the answer once it allows me to, thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873384/how-to-deep-copy-a-list on the gotchas of deep copy