# Variable changes without being touched

Tags: python, list, math, matrix, copy

I'm quite new to Python but this is strange.
So, I have a matrix (a list of lists) and I pass it to a function (creaMatrixVNS).

```
def creaMatrixVNS(best_matrice, time):
    matrice = best_matrice
    sol_init_ass = assegnamento(matrice)

    iteration = 1 #numero swap
    counter = 0 #numero iterazioni

    while True:
            temp = matrice
```

From this point

```
            for x in xrange(0,iteration):
                    temp = swap(temp, sol_init_ass)
```

to this point, I see that my variable `matrice` changes and is set to the value of temp. And I don't know why. That's the second part of the function.

```
            time2 = creaSoluzione(temp)

            if time2 < time:
                    time = time2
                    matrice = temp
                    if counter == 9:
                            break
                    else:
                            counter += 1
            else:
                    if iteration < 3:
                            iteration += 1
                            counter = 0
                    else:
                            break

    print(time)
    return matrice
```

Other functions:

```
def swap(matriceInput, lista):
        result = matriceInput

        i1, j1 = giveMeAcouple(lista)
        i2, j2 = giveMeAcouple(lista)

        while i1 == i2 and j1 == j2:
                i1, j1 = giveMeAcouple(lista)
                i2, j2 = giveMeAcouple(lista)

        result[i1][j1], result[i2][j2] = result[i2][j2], result[i1][j1]

        return result

def giveMeAcouple(sol_init_ass):
        j1 = randint(0,len(sol_init_ass)-1)
        while len(sol_init_ass[j1]) <= 0:
                j1 = randint(0,len(sol_init_ass)-1)

        i1 = randint(0,len(sol_init_ass[j1]) - 1)

        return sol_init_ass[j1][i1], j1


def assegnamento(matrice):
        listElementi = []
        temp = []
        n = len(matrice)
        m = len(matrice[0])

        for i in xrange(0,m): #Per ogni colonna
                for j in xrange(0,n): #Per ogni riga
                        if matrice[j][i] != 0:
                                temp.append(j)
                listElementi.append(temp)
                temp = []

        return listElementi


def creaSoluzione(matrix):
        n = len(matrix)
        m = len(matrix[0])

        max = 0
        for j in xrange(0,m):
                temp = 0
                for i in xrange(0,n):
                        temp += matrix[i][j]
                #print(temp)

                if temp > max:
                        max = temp
        return max
```

Any hints? Thanks

Comment: Doing `matrice = best_matrice` does not make a copy.

Comment: So I'm simply add another name to the same variable? How can I make a copy?

Comment: what does `sol_init_ass` stand for? It seems so weird… I can think of a lot of phrases… :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `matrice = best_matrice`, you're just creating a new reference named `matrice` pointing to the same object as the reference `best_matrice`.

Check out the accepted answer for [Deep copy a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873384/deep-copy-a-list-in-python) for an example of a deep copy of a list in Python.

Answer (score -1):

A quick shorthand for copying lists 'deeply' without importing is the use of the `:` slice operator. In your situation, you'd need to use it twice to explicitly duplicate the lists and their contents rather than copying references to the inner lists.

A trivial example is `new_lst = old_lst[:]` to copy all contents of `old_lst` -- in your case, you'd want to do `matrice = best_matrice[:][:]`, thereby copying the contents of the inner lists, too.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the slice operator is not a deep copy.  Consider ```a = [1,2]; b = [3,4]; lst1 = [a, b]; lst2 = lst1[:]; b.append(5); print lst2 ```

Comment: I put 'deeply' in quotes for a reason, but it is actually a 'deep' copy - just one level deep. When you say `a = [1,2]` you're really saying "let 'a' be a name that refers to a list in memory somewhere containing 1 and 2". `b = a` is just saying, "let 'b' be a name referring to 'a'." The `[:]` idiom simply changes that to "let 'b' be a name referring to a list whose contents are whatever the contents of 'a' are, right now". If those contents happen to be names or references themselves, that's what you get. If you want a 2-level deep copy, `lst[:][:]` is the right idiom.

Comment: lst[:][:] just copies the first layer twice: `l=[ ['one'], ['two']];l2=l[:][:];l2[0][0]='three';print l` gives `[['three'], ['two']]`

Comment: Hey, you're right! I've been doing it wrong. Thanks