# Values for a list variable is changing despite there being no explicit changes

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

The variable 'operations' which is a list is changing after the for loop is run despite their being no line that explicitly says for its value to change. Here is my code:

```
validOperations = ['(', ')', '^', '*', '/', '+', '-']
operations = ['+', '*', '/']
newOp = operations  

for y in range(len(newOp) - 1):
        for z in range(len(newOp) - 1):
                if(validOperations.index(newOp[z]) > validOperations.index(newOp[z+1])):
                        oldVal = newOp[z]
                        newOp[z] = newOp[z+1]
                        newOp[z+1] = newOp[z]
                        print(newOp)
                        print(operations)
```

What can I do to make it to where the value of operations stays constant?

Comment: `newOp = operations` doesn't make a copy. See http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2):

`newOP` is not a copy of `operatoions`. `newOp` is an alias for `operations`. Which means that when `newOP` changes, `operations` changes as well. You need to tell Python explicitly to copy your list:

`newOp = operations[:]`

If your list is more than one level deep in nesting however, using slice notation will fail. You must use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873384/deep-copy-a-list-in-python) instead.

Comment: Note: This works in this case, but for more complex structures, you need to use [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

Comment: @TemporalWolf Yes. I'll metion that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for responding, I have been working with this for a couple of days and not finding an answer was driving me crazy.