# Python: How to deep copy a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list whose each element is a dictionary.
Each element looks something like this

`{'CELL': <Cell SOW16007.2.AC7>, 'COUNT': 2, 'NAMELIST': [], 'NAME': u'', 'LEVEL': u'SSE'}`

I need to make a backup of this list.Normal assignment  or using shallow copy is not option i can use as i will making changes to the original.
But when i use deepcopy 
`backUpNames=deepcopy(oldNames)` 
I'm getting an error :

**`TypeError: unhashable type: 'array.array'`**

**What wrong am i doing here? How can i solve this?**

This is a not a duplicate question as I have already used deepcopy, problem i am facing is with the error deepcopy is throwing.

*Minimal Code:*

Using openpxl i iterate the sheet and append the values to a list

```
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(sys.argv[3],data_only=True)
_ts=wb.active 
oldNames.append({'NAME':_ts['G7'].value,'LEVEL':_ts['H7'].value,'CELL':_ts['F7'],'COUNT':0,'NAMELIST':[]})
backUpNames=deepcopy(oldNames)#error occurring here
```

Thank You

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri - That's not a duplicate at all. OP is using `copy.deepcopy` already, and getting an error.

Comment: Won't this give syntax error? `<Cell SOW16007.2.AC7>`

Comment: From given error, I can assume that `Cell` is some complex type that doesn't support hashing. Can You confirm by trying this: `from collections import Hashable; isinstance(d['CELL'], Hashable)`?

Comment: What is `each` there?

Comment: @Fejs i'm getting it as `True`

Comment: @Fejs each was a cell object.Output of type(each) is `<class 'openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell'>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deep copy a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873384/deep-copy-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

```
import copy
list = [{'a':1,'b':2},{'c':3,'d':4}]
cpy_list = []
for li in list:
    d2 = copy.deepcopy(li)
    cpy_list.append(d2)
print cpy_list
```

Comment: What's the point here? OP said he knows how to use `deepcopy`, he have a specific problem, for which this doesn't help a bit.

Comment: I still get the same error TypeError: unhashable type: 'array.array'.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this will fix the problem:

```
oldNames.append({'NAME':_ts['G7'].value,'LEVEL':_ts['H7'].value,'CELL':_ts['F7'].value,'COUNT':0,'NAMELIST':[]})
```

Note this `key/value` pair: `'CELL':_ts['F7'].value`

I suppose that You can't use cell as object here, but rather only it's value.