# Python: Copy an `array.array`

Tags: python, arrays, copy

Is there a way to copy an [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) (not a `list`) in Python, besides just creating a new one and copying values, or using `.to_something` and `.from_something`? I can't seem to find anything in the documentation. If not, is there a similar builtin datatype that can do this?

I am working on a high-performance module, so the faster the answer, the better.

My current solution is just using `.to_bytes` and `.from_bytes`, which is about 1.8 times faster from my tests.

Comment: You can use deepcopy and list - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873384/deep-copy-a-list-in-python

Comment: Is this what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list

Comment: How about `a[:]`?

Comment: @Stefan Tested that, it's about the same as my current way, but sometimes slower. And yeah, idk why everyone thinks I was referring to `list`s.

Comment: Can you show your tests?

Comment: I have another one that looks faster in *my* tests, but I'm not going to post it if you're using different tests anyway and mine aren't compatible...

Comment: the `[:]` notation is literally the closest to `memcpy` in `C`. I can't imagine of anything faster than that.

Comment: Yeah, trying it again, `[:]` is faster. Maybe my tests were off. They weren't super consistent in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what your `array.array` includes, but using a sample:

```
>>> import array
>>> a = array.array('i', [1, 2, 3] * 1000)
array('i', [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1,
2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, ... ])
```

## Some set up:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> import numpy as np
```

## Timing various methods

#### (using the %timeit magic in a Jupyter Notebook):

**Slicing**

```
In [1]: %timeit cp = a[:]

418 ns ± 4.89 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

**Deepcopy**

```
In [2]: %timeit cp = deepcopy(a)

1.83 µs ± 34 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

**numpy copy ... NOTE: This produces a numpy array, not an array.array**

```
In [3]: %timeit cp = np.copy(a)

1.87 µs ± 62.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

**List Comprehension and array.array conversion**

```
In [4]: %timeit cp = array.array('i', [item for item in a])

147 µs ± 5.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**numpy copy and array.array conversion**

```
In [5]: %timeit cp = array.array('i', np.copy(a))

310 µs ± 2.25 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**Copying to an existing array**

```
In[6]: pre = array.array('i', [0, 0, 0] * 1000)
In[7]: %timeit for i, element in enumerate(a): pre[i] = a[i]

344 µs ± 7.83 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: The one I mentioned I found to be faster is `a * 1`. I suspect under the hood it's equivalent to `a[:]` but it gets under the hood more quickly (as in, it reaches the copying code more quickly: https://ideone.com/KLb3wl). Only noticeable with small arrays, though.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, `array.array` can't store mutable items. So there's no point in using `copy.deepcopy` instead of `copy.copy`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need numpy to copy an `array.array` object. And since `array.array` objects can only contain ints, floats, or unicode characters, the concept of "shallow copy" and "deep copy" don't apply here.

You can just use the `[:]` trick to make a copy of an `array.array()` object:

```
>>> import array
>>> x = array.array('B', b'\xFF' * 10)
>>> x
array('B', [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255])
>>> y = x[:]
>>> y
array('B', [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255])
```

You can also pass it to the `array.array()` initializer function.

For example:

```
>>> import array
>>> x = array.array('B', b'\xFF' * 10)
>>> x
array('B', [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255])
>>> y = array.array('B', x)
>>> y
array('B', [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255])
```

Be sure to pass the same "type code" (the `'B'` in the above example) for the new `array.array` object.

Answer (score 0):

`copy.copy(arr)` would work fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18429898)

Comment: @31piy How exactly does it not answer the question? Rather looks like you didn't read the question. And how does this "critique or request clarification"?