# Game of life neighbours issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to create my [Game of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) code in python, but when it checks for the living neighbours, it seems to have a problem. I've been tried to solve it for 2 days but I still don't know what I'm missing.
Here is the code broken up into pieces.

```
from random import randrange
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
root = Tk()
canv = Canvas(width = 800, height = 800)
canv.pack()

def value():
    if randrange(16) == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

I set up the canvas in tkinter and create a function which determines the state of a cell, so every cell has 1/x chance at being alive first.

```
def pprint(lst):
    for row in lst:
        print(row)
```

I created a pretty-print function when I tried to debug.

```
def nb(life,row,col):
    count = 0
    #print(x,y)
    #print(life[x][y])
    for r in [row-1, row, row+1]:
        for c in [col-1,col,col+1]:
            if life[r][c] == 1:
                count += 1
    if life[row][col] == 1:
        count -= 1
    #print(count,end=" ")
    return count
```

This function it supposed to return the number of living neighbours a cell has. (notes remained from debugging all over the code)

```
def ud(life,life2,size,box):        
    #print(life)        
    while True:
        try:
            for row in range(1,size+1):
                for col in range(1,size+1):
                    #print(row,col)
                    a = nb(life,row,col)
                    print("[{0},{1}]".format(row,col), end =" ")
                    print(a, end=" ")
                    
                    if ((1<a) and (a<4)):
                        life2[row][col] = 1
                        canv.itemconfig(box[row-1][col-1], fill ="black")
                                                    
                    else:
                        life2[row][col] = 0
                        canv.itemconfig(box[row-1][col-1], fill ="white")
                print("")                         
            print("ok")
            #print(life2[19][19])
            root.update()
            pprint(life)
            #sleep(5)

            life = life2
            sleep(800/size**2)
            print("")
        except:
            break
```

This is the main updating function. It's supposed to run the nb function for every cell in the life 2d array and the determine it's value in life2. "box" is a 2d array, which contains the rectangle tkinter id for every cell on the visual grid. (Yes, print functions are also for debugging.)

```
#######
size = 10
w = 10
box = [[canv.create_rectangle(y*w,x*w,y*w+10,x*w+10) for y in range(size)] for x in range(size)]
life = [[value() for y in range(size)] for x in range(size)]
life2 = [[0 for y in range(size+2)] for x in range(size+2)]
for i in range(1,size+1):
    life2[i] = [0] + life[i-1] + [0]
#life = life2

pprint(life)
root.update()
ud(life2,life2,size,box)

del box
del life
del life2
```

I create the box variable (w = width of a cell) and generate the random living cells. Then I create a "0" frame for "life" (so the program doesn't break on the nb checking when it's at the corners. And I know I could've use try/except). Then I launch the ud function with the parameters (size = number of cells in a row; both life-matrix arguments are life2, because the 2nd will be completely rewritten in theory)

So what is the problem with the program?

Comment: All you've told us about what's wrong is "it seems to have a problem."  In what way?  Are you getting unexpected results?  If so, what are you getting, and what did you expect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deep copy a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873384/deep-copy-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `life = life2` inside `def ud(life,life2,size,box):` makes it so that `life` and `live2` both name/point to the same data. You need to *deep copy* `life2` and let `life` point to that absolutely seperate data.

*Deep copy*, because your `life2` contains other lists and if you only *shallow copy* by doing `live = life2[:]` you would still have the same problem - live would then have unique refs to list inside of itself, but the data the refs of the inner lists point to would still be shared. You use  [`import copy` & `copy.deepcopy(...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) for deep copying.

---

**Renaming**:

```
import copy
print()
a = [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]
b = a  # second name, same data
a[0] = [0,8,15]    # replaces the ref on a[0] with a new one, b == a 
a[1][2] = 99       # modifies a value inside the 2nd list ref, b == a
print (a,"=>",b)   # b is just another name for a
```

*Output*:

```
# nothing got preserved, both identical as b ist just another name for a
([[0, 8, 15], [2, 4, 99]], '=>', [[0, 8, 15], [2, 4, 99]])
```

**Shallow Copy**:

```
a = [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]
b = a[:]  # shallow copy
a[0] = [0,8,15]       # replaces one ref with a new one (only in a)
a[1][2] = 99          # modifies the value inside 2nd list, same ref in a&b
print (a,"=>",b)
```

*Output*:

```
# b got "unique" refs to the inner lists, if we replace one in a 
# this does not reflect in b as its ref is unique. chaning values 
# inside a inner list, will be reflected, as they are not uniqe
([[0, 8, 15], [2, 4, 99]], '=>', [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 99]])
```

**Deep Copy**:

```
a = [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)  # deep copy
a[0] = [0,8,15]       # only a modified
a[1][2] = 99          # only in a modified
print (a,"=>",b)
```

*Output*:

```
# completely independent - b shares no refs with former a, all got new'ed up
([[0, 8, 15], [2, 4, 99]], '=>', [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]])
```

---

If you replace the `print`'s above with

```
print(id(a), id(a[0]), id(a[1]), id(b), id(b[0]), id(b[1]))
```

you get the output of the unique IDs of `a` and it's contend as well as of `b` and its content:

*rename*:

```
`a`: 139873593089632, 139873593146976, 139873593072384 
`b`: 139873593089632, 139873593146976, 139873593072384
```

*shallow*:

```
`a`: 139873593229040, 139873593089632, 139873593146040
`b`: 139873593227168, 139873593088552, 139873593146040
```

*deep*:

```
`a`: 139873593253968, 139873593227168, 139873593072384
`b`: 139873593229040, 139873593089632, 139873593254112
```