# Deep cloning List Object

Tags: c#, list, collections, clone

I need to know how to deep clone a `List <Business>` object. I tried the following:

```
List< Business> owner = bus.Select(m => new Business{
    Businessname= m.Businessname,
    Locations= m.Locations,

 }).ToList();
```

I removed an object (`Locations` - Locations is a `List <Country>`) from `owner` object. I expected no changes in the `bus` object as I cloned it as shown in the above code.

However, the object `Locations` has also got deleted from the `bus` object. Can someone tell me how to fix this ?

Comment: `Locations= m.Locations,`, that's not in any way a clone, that's only a reference assignment. If you want to clone, you will need to do something like `m.Locations.Select(l => new Country { ... }).ToList()`

Comment: I am getting an error. In the `owner ` object there are also some `Locations` which are `null`. So, when it tries to clone the `Country` it hits an error. How could I prevent this from happening ? Help

Comment: @SiavashGhanbari Did you read the content of what you shared above. It's in Python and not C#.

Comment: that's my fault, I deleted the flag and comment @sharonHwk

Comment: Any help on this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deep copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873384/how-to-deep-copy-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

You should perform your clone operation as follows:

```
List< Business> owner = bus.Select(m => new Business
{
    Businessname = m.Businessname,
    Locations = m.Locations?.Select(l => new Country { /*here goes your initialization*/})
})
.ToList();
```

The operator `?` does null check and if `Locations` field is `null` it stops execution and returns `null`, otherwise it performs `Select` operation.

Please, note that if `Country` object also contains reference typed fields, you should explicitly create that objects and copy all the fields.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most universal way of deep-cloning pretty much any object or data structure is to serialize and de-serialize it back. Newtonsoft JSON is pretty fast and smart enough to handle complex scenarios such as circular references, interface-typed fields and more.

```
var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myList);
var deepCopy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(str);
```

However, this is probably not the fastest way, since it does a lot of extra work and allocations.