# Why are changes to tempArray affecting the parentArray?

Tags: python, replit

In my current code of nested while loops, I have a statement to reload the `tempSequence` variable equal to the original sequence variable. However, through print-checking, you can see `del(tempSequence[i])` is removing the value from both the `tempSquence` and sequence variables.  I don't understand why the parent sequence is being affected in this way.

I have tried storing the `sequence` variable within the beginning of the outer loop, adding a new list inside the loop to store the original data, as well as moving the `tempSequence = sequence` statement multiple places throughout the code.

The easy way --> Repl.it [link](https://repl.it/@WingsOverEden/Code-Signal-almostIncreasingSequence-Challenge)

The other way:

```
while i <= len(sequence):

    tempSequence = sequence **<<<< this doesn't work but**

    del(tempSequence[i])
    print(sequence)
    print(tempSequence)

    j = 0  **<<<< This works every loop**
```

The expected result would be for tempSequence to be reset equal to the original array.  Then altered and iterated.

The actual result leaves the array short one value each iteration, ending with a too short range to complete all iterations

Comment: Simply assigning lists in Python creates a shallow copy, wherein changes are reflected in the original list as well. You should [deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873384/how-to-deep-copy-a-list) the `sequence`.

Comment: Thank you very much TheGamer007, this should fix my code and I learned something new.