# Create a copy of a list whose changes won't affect the initial list

Tags: python, list, sorting

If I have a list like

```
a=[1,4,2]
```

and I create a new list in the following way

```
b=a
```

I found out that any modification to `b` would be applied to `a` as well:

```
b.sort()
print b
print a
b.pop(-1)
print b
print a
```

How can I create a copy of a list which I can modify at pleasure without affecting the original?

So, in my example, every time I print `a` I want to obtain the initial output `[1,4,2]`, no matter what I do to `b`.

Comment: You need to use a deep copy operation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873384/how-to-deep-copy-a-list

Comment: You can create a copy with `b=a[:]`

Comment: If the values in your list are simple integers, you can create a copy with `b = a[:]` as @yatu commented.

Answer (score 0):

use  `b =a.copy()`

then use `b.sort()`

```
assert a==b
```

result  `False`

Comment: @3sm1r it's working for you, that's matter.