# Writing to variable with 2-dimensional array causes it to change value of array

Tags: python, arrays

So I have the variable `test`, that accesses an item of a 2-dimensional array. Then, I want to change one item of `test`, but not from the original array. But somehow, it still changes it although I stored the value in a seperate variable. Here's my code:

```
config = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

test = config[0]

test[0] = 45                                               

print(config)
```

When I run this, the first element of the first array of `config` has changed to 45, so `config` is now:

```
config = [[45, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Can anybody explain this behaviour and help me so that when I change a element of `test`, `config` doesn't change?

*Edit: I don't think it is a duplicate of an other question, because I've already tried:

*Note: after each option, obviously `test = temp_config[0]` is run instead of `test = config[0]`.

1: `temp_config = config.copy()`

2: `temp_config = config[:]`

3: `temp_config = []; temp_config.extend(config)`

4: `temp_config = list(config)`

5: `temp_config = list(config)`

6: `temp_config = copy.copy(config)`

7: `temp_config = [i for i in config]`

8: `temp_config = []; for item in config: temp_config.append(item)`

While editing this question, I noticed that ONLY copy.deepcopy() works, NONE of the other suggested options.

Comment: @Austin OP has nested lists. They need a `deepcopy`. Consider changing the duplicate target to the following: [How to deep copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873384/how-to-deep-copy-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

Make config readonly or copy config to a tempConfig and do operations on tempConfig while config will remain intact

Comment: how do I make config readonly?