# Copying a list of objects and retaining their properties in Python

Tags: python, list, object, mutation

Sometimes we don't want things to change. In the code below, my original `Things` are mutated, even though I made a copy of the list containing them. I'm not that surprised, but I'd like to know how to store my original object properties so I can restore my `things` list to exactly how it was when first created.

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.x)

things = [Thing(10), Thing(20)]
original_things = things.copy()

for thing in things:
    print(thing)
print("All change")
things[0].x = 30
things[1].x = 40
print("Back to the beginning?")
things = original_things
for thing in things:
    print(thing)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deep copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873384/how-to-deep-copy-a-list)

Comment: also use tuple when need immutable

Answer (score 0):

## Read the docs, Luke!

[Python documentation for lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) says:

> list.**copy**(x)
>
> Return a shallow copy of the list. Equivalent to `a[:]`.

Therefore, `bar_list = foo_list.copy()` is equivalent to `bar_list = foo_list`.

As per @Gphilo, what you want is `copy.deepcopy`:

```py
from copy import deepcopy
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.x)

things = [Thing(10), Thing(20)]
original_things = deepcopy(things)

for thing in things:
    print(thing)
print("All change")
things[0].x = 30
things[1].x = 40
print("Back to the beginning!")
things = original_things
for thing in things:
    print(thing)
```

Output:

```
10
20
All change
Back to the beginning!
10
20
```