# How do I extract and edit a dict value without editing the dict itself?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, key-value

I have a dictionary where the keys are letters, and the values are arrays.  I want to extract one of the arrays, and then pop a value from it, without changing the dictionary.

```
mydict = {'a': ['apple', 'avocado'], 
          'b': ['banana', 'berry'], 
          'c': ['carrot', 'cucumber']}

fruits = mydict['a']
fruits.pop(0)
```

When I print the dict I then get:

```
>> {'a': ['avocado'], 'b': ['banana', 'berry'], 'c': ['carrot', 'cucumber']}
```

How do I get a copy of the list that won't change the dictionary when I pop from it?

Comment: Also here's a working [repl.it project](https://repl.it/@HarunYlmaz/GleamingGreenRhombus) I just created. You just need to create a `list` from `mydict['a']` as `fruits = list(mydict['a'])`

Comment: `fruits = mydict['a'].copy()`. Or, even better, `fruits = mydict['a'][1:]` to get all but the first element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ust the `.copy()` attribute when assigning the `fruit` variable.

```
>>> mydict = {'a': ['apple', 'avocado'], 
              'b': ['banana', 'berry'], 
              'c': ['carrot', 'cucumber']}

>>> fruits = mydict['a'].copy()
>>> fruits.pop(0)
```

This will give the following results

```
>>> mydict

{'a': ['apple', 'avocado'],
 'b': ['banana', 'berry'],
 'c': ['carrot', 'cucumber']}

>>> fruits

['avocado']
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for this.  I didn't realise my question was actually about list assignment and not dictionaries.  Now that I see this, I realise that fruits = mydict['a'] doesn't create a new list, it just points to the original list (inside the dict).  And your .copy() solves this for me by creating a new list.

Answer (score 2):

The `=` operator creates a new variable or data structure, but it basically points to the same object as before. So using the `=` operator won't work.

You can use the `list.copy()` method which returns a [shallow copy](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) of the list in the dictionary. Modifying this list will not modify the original dictionary.

```
mydict = {'a': ['apple', 'avocado'], 
          'b': ['banana', 'berry'], 
          'c': ['carrot', 'cucumber']}

fruits = mydict['a'].copy()
fruits.pop(0)

print(fruits) # returns ['avocado']
print(mydict) # returns {'a': ['apple', 'avocado'] ...}
```

Alternatively, use the Python [copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) module's `copy()` or `deepcopy()` method which will both work.

```
import copy

mydict = {'a': ['apple', 'avocado'], 
          'b': ['banana', 'berry'], 
          'c': ['carrot', 'cucumber']}

fruits = copy.copy(mydict['a']) # or copy.deepcopy(mydict['a'])
fruits.pop(0)

print(fruits) # returns ['avocado']
print(mydict) # returns {'a': ['apple', 'avocado'] ...}
```

The distinction between shallow (the `copy()` method) and deep copying (the `deepcopy()` method) is important but does not really apply in this case, because you are not copying a *nested* data structure (your dictionary) but only a list within that dictionary.

For example, shallow copying the dict and modifying the nested list also modifies the original:

```
import copy

mydict = {'a': ['apple', 'avocado'], 
          'b': ['banana', 'berry'], 
          'c': ['carrot', 'cucumber']}

fruits = copy.copy(mydict)
fruits['a'].append('apricot') # also changes mydict

print(fruits) # returns {'a': ['apple', 'avocado', 'apricot'] ...}
print(mydict) # also returns {'a': ['apple', 'avocado', 'apricot'] ...}
```

While deep copying does not:

```
import copy

mydict = {'a': ['apple', 'avocado'], 
          'b': ['banana', 'berry'], 
          'c': ['carrot', 'cucumber']}

fruits = copy.deepcopy(mydict)
fruits['a'].append('apricot') # also changes mydict

print(fruits) # returns {'a': ['apple', 'avocado', 'apricot'] ...}
print(mydict) # returns {'a': ['apple', 'avocado'] ...}
```

From the [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) on the copy module:

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects
> (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):
>
> - A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible)
>   inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
> - A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies
>   into it of the objects found in the original.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive and clear answer, this is awesome.  I marked the shorter version from Desi Pilla as the answer because deepcopy is not required for this question. But I appreciate the full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

[Deep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Deep_copy) copy:

```
import copy
fruits = copy.deepcopy(my_dict["a"])
```

[Shallow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Shallow_copy) copy:

```
import copy
fruits = copy.copy(my_dict["a"])
```

```
fruits = my_dict["a"].copy()
```

```
fruits = list(my_dict["a"])
```

As all your elements are of type `str`, shallow copy the lists. `str` objects are immutable, so their internal state cannot be modified. Whenever you "modify" a `str`, you actually just make a copy.

[More details on deep copying in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17873384/7395227)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get a specific value (in this case "avocado"), and you want it in list form, you just surround the expression in square brackets and it becomes a list like so:

```
fruits = [mydict["a"][1]]
```

Comment: This neither results in the expected result. It works if there are only 2 items in the list, but not if there are more. Hence "specific", I assume.

Answer (score -4):

Instead of using pop use index to get the item. It will leave your array inside in the dict intact.

```
fruit = mydict['a'][0]
```

Comment: The expected result is `fruits = ["avocado"]`, not `fruit = "apple"`.