# Slicing and performance

Tags: python, time-complexity

It might be that I don't understand slicing that well.
I want to add one list from a particular index to another list. I was wondering, because I read that if you slice a list that you make a (deep)copy of it. Which method below is faster?

method 1

```
new_lst += old_lst[i:]
```

method 2

```
while i < len(old_lst):
    new_list.append(old_lst[i])
    i += 1
```

Comment: Slice is a shallow copy, not a deep copy.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck.

Comment: First method is faster than using hand-written `for` loop.

Comment: Probably the first, but why didn't you just time it and see?

Comment: Append is a slow process. However, both methods create a shallow copy: see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873384/how-to-deep-copy-a-list) on how to create a deep copy of a list.

Comment: I would think you want to use extend instead, like `new_lst.extend(old_lst)`.

Comment: the while loop will call `append` too many times which produces function overhead. `[i:]` will make a copy of your array in 1 call.

Comment: There are multiple related posts you can read first: [How to deep copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17873384/2745495) to address the misconception on deepcopying a list, and [How do I concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1720421/2745495) to see other ways to extend new_list with contents from old_list. And as mentioned, you can always time it yourself to see which is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` loop will call append multiple times which produces function overhead. `[:]` (shallow copy) on the other hand will make a copy of your array in one call. However if your elements are not literals (if they're a list for example) then you will end up accidentally sharing the pointers between lists. If you really want to deep copy, then utilize `from copy import deepcopy` which will deep copy your iterable.

Comment: Both methods make shallow copies, so they have the same sharing behavior for the list elements.

Comment: @Barmar I said that in my post. `However if your elements are not literalrs then you wil ... share pointers.` and `utilize ... deepcopy will will deep copy`

Comment: I misunderstood what you were referring to when you said "on the other hand". You were distinguishing the number of calls, not whether it's a shallow copy.

Comment: @Barmar that's correct. Though If I were wrong, I appreciate your attempt to correct me. Maybe someone will misunderstand like you and this chat would help him understand.