# Changes made in Python list showing up in copy of original list

Tags: python, list

I'm making some changes to a list, however, these changes are being reflected in the copy of the original list.

I tried using these methods but they didn't work:

```
copy_list = list(org_list)
copy_list = org_list[:]
copy_list = org_list.copy()
```

Here's my code followed by the output. Where am I going wrong?

```
name = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
desc = [["1"], ['1', '2'], [], ['1', '2'], []]

desc1 = desc.copy()

for n, d in zip(name, desc):
    d.insert(0, n)

print(desc1)
```

Output (the alphabets shouldn't be visible):

```
[['A', '1'], ['B', '1', '2'], ['C'], ['D', '1', '2'], ['E']]
```

Comment: You might need to use deepcopy instead of just copy

Comment: `from copy import deepcopy`. Use this function instead.

Comment: @MB-F Not the best duplicate since the OP here already made a shallow copy which is the correct solution to the question you linked.

Comment: @schwobaseggl You are right, though the answer is very thorough and covers the case of this question too. I think it makes sense to have it linked for more information while your answer here directly solves the specific problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
from copy import deepcopy

desc1 = deepcopy(desc)
```

`list.copy` only makes a shallow copy: a new `list` object, but its elements (here mutable sublists) will be references to the same objects as the elements of the original.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that desc1 is a copy of desc but the lists inside desc are not copied, they are the same.
Code to verify that -

```
name = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
desc = [["1"], ['1', '2'], [], ['1', '2'], []]

desc1 = desc.copy()

print(desc1 is desc)
print(desc1[0] is desc[0])
```

Output:

```
False
True
```

To solve that you could use deepcopy as suggested by @schwobaseggl or

```
name = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
desc = [["1"], ['1', '2'], [], ['1', '2'], []]

desc1 = [row.copy() for row in desc]

for n, d in zip(name, desc):
    d.insert(0, n)

print(desc1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a copy of the *list* by default creates a *shallow copy*, which means the elements of the list are copied as-is into a new list.
Native data types like int, str, bool etc will get copied but Complex data types like *list*, *dict*, *object* etc store only the pointer in the list. Hence when creating a copy() the pointer gets copied over.

Using [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) creates copies of each of the elements and sub-elements giving a true copy

```
from copy import deepcopy

name = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
desc = [["1"], ['1', '2'], [], ['1', '2'], []]

desc1 = deepcopy(desc)

for n, d in zip(name, desc):
    d.insert(0, n)

print(desc1)
```

For more information:
[How to deep copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873384/how-to-deep-copy-a-list)