# How does a double for-loop iterate?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am having problems with my for loops. moreover with multiple for loops, I don't seem to understand how they work.

herunder is my double for loop i want to implement in a genetic algorithm. The input of the code: `population` is an arraylist such as the `mating_pool`:

```
mating_pool = [[1,4,7,2,8,2],[3,5,6,8,5,4]]
```

`r_mutation` is the rate of mutation of a single element, anywhere in the population. i.e. the chance that a single element mutates.

```
def mutation(population,r_mutation):
    mut_pop = population
    for _i in range(len(population)):
        for _j in range(len(population[_i])):
            _ = random.randint(0,100)
            if _ < 100*r_mutation:
                mut_pop[_i][_j]    = random.randint(0,20)
    return mut_pop

r_mutation = 0.80
mutated_pop = mutation(mating_pool, r_mutation)
```

In my case, even with high `r_mutation`, `mutated_pop` equals `mating_pool` at every point. I want the integers in the `population` to mutate with a chance of 80%. How can I solve this?

Comment: "pops out as the same as the input" - it doesn't. I ran this twice and got `[[1, 4, 7, 10, 8, 2], [3, 5, 6, 8, 5, 4]]` and `[[1, 4, 7, 10, 8, 1], [3, 11, 19, 8, 5, 19]]`. Your code has randomness, but no change is a valid outcome.

Comment: I mean, sure, `mutated_pop == mating_pool` because you're modifying `mating_pool` in-place

Comment: BTW, the correct term is ***nested** loop*.

Comment: How many times did you try it?  There's almost a 7% chance of no mutations occurring on a given run.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your fast replies. I have the code running on pupulation of 15x48. with an r_mutation of over 0.90, and the output is the same as the input

Comment: How do *you* know that the output is the same as the input?

Comment: I have updated the question slightly to better reflect the problem. my mut_pop is the same as population every single run of the algorithm.

Comment: @ForceBru  I have changed the code to be not in-place. my outputs, however are still the same..

Comment: Your example code still mutates the original lists and still works as expected. Your problem is not reproducible.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny thank you for your reply. How can I keep the original list unaltered? I.e. create a new list? I expected it to keep population the same because I transferred it to mut_pop before the coding

Comment: Please make shure the [mre] matches the problem. Does this help? [How to deep copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17873384/14277722).

Answer (score 0):

```py
_ = random.randint(0,100)
if _ < 100*r_mutation:
    population[_i][_j]    = random.randint(0,20)
```

So, `_` is a random number between 0 and 100, right?. And then you mutate a element if... the random number is lower than 100.

Given that you have a random number between 0 and 100, I'd say that there's a 20% chance that the number is lower than 20, wouldn't you?
So replacing the mutation with

```py
    if _ > 20
        population[_i][_j] = new_mutated_value
```

Comment: "you mutate a element if... the random number is lower than 100" - OP's code defines `r_mutation = 0.80`, so the element is mutated if `_ < 100 * 0.8`, so is the random number is lower than 80 which happens about 80% of the time, doesn't it? Basically, OP's code does the same thing as the `if _ > 20` example

Comment: yes, i believe this part is not really the problem. I think the code itself works, but it rewrites the original input `population` aswell as the `mutated_pop` im trying to find something for that but the arrays are a bit of a pain.