# How to pass a matrix as an argument without changing its original values in Python

Tags: python, pass-by-value

I am trying to pass a matrix (list of lists) as an argument to a function. I want to keep the original matrix values intact. How can I implement this in python? I have tried to copy the matrix in a new variable temp, but it is still not working.

```py
ideal = [[5,1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20],[21,22,23,24,25]]
print(ideal)
for i in range(1):
    temp = ideal
    print(rotate_col_down(temp,i))
print(ideal)
```

output:

```py
[[5, 1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 23, 23, 24, 25]] #ideal
[[21, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 7, 8, 9, 10], [6, 12, 13, 14, 15], [11, 17, 18, 19, 20], [16, 23, 23, 24, 25]]
[[21, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 7, 8, 9, 10], [6, 12, 13, 14, 15], [11, 17, 18, 19, 20], [16, 23, 23, 24, 25]] # changed ideal
```

Here is the function that i am trying to implement

```
def rotate_col_down(state, j):
    temp = state[ROWS-1][j]
    for i in range(ROWS-1,0,-1):
        state[i][j]= state[i-1][j]
    state[0][j] = temp
    return(state)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ran into the fact that python is mostly pass-by-reference instead of value (compare [this post with answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)).

You can solve this in your code by using `.copy()` or `copy.deepcopy()` (compare [how-to-deep-copy-a-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873384/how-to-deep-copy-a-list))

So a solution would be

```py
import copy

ideal = [[5,1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20],[21,22,23,24,25]]

print(ideal)
for i in range(1):
    print(rotate_col_down(copy.deepcopy(ideal),i))
print(ideal)
```

Comment: Good answer, but if a question has been answered before, it's better to flag the question as duplicate than to provide a new answer.