# Why first items are removed from both lists?

Tags: python, list

```
list1 = [
    [0,1,2,3,4],
    [0,1,2,3,4]
]
list2 = list1.copy()
for i in range(len(list2)):
    list2[i].pop(0)
print(list1)#[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
print(list2)#[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Copying list1 with copy() method in list2 and removing items from nested lists in list2 it shouldn't remove those items in list1. Why it happens?????

Comment: You need a deep copy. `from copy import deepcopy` then `list2 = deepcopy(list1)`

Comment: Thankssss!!! Everything works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deep copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873384/how-to-deep-copy-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because of the **difference** between a ***shallow copy*** vs a ***deep copy***. `copy()` creates a shallow copy vs `deepcopy()` creates a deep copy. Here's what the documentation has to say:

> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the
> extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
> the original. A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then,
> recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the
> original.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `copy()` operation is not independent,you could use look at the `deepcopy()`.If you want a nomarl copy operation, you could use `deepcopy()` to do that.

Answer (score 0):

complementing the before answers, you can change to this:

```
import copy

list1: list[list[int]] = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
]
list2 = copy.deepcopy(list1)
for pos, items in enumerate(list2):
    list2[pos].pop(0)
print(list1)  # [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
print(list2)  # [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```