# Why does removing items from list while iterating over it skip every other item

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, foreach

When iterating over a list and removing each item, why is every other item skipped and not removed? (I realise it may be bad practise to do this I just want to understand what is going on)

```
lst=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for item in lst:
    lst.remove(item)
print(lst)
```

Expected output: `[]`
Actual output: `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`

Comment: This answers it maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207427/9227188

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happens here is the following:

You start with the following list:
`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Then, in the first iteration of the for loop, you get the first item of the list which is `0`, and remove it from the list. The updated list now looks like:
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Then, at the second iteration of the loop, you get the second item **in the updated list**. Here, that second item is not `1` anymore but it is `2` (because you look at the updated list), so you remove `2` from the list. The updated list now looks like:
`[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

And it goes on... until you get:
`[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`

Answer (score 2):

To get the expected output, you need to iterate over a [shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270374/how-to-make-a-shallow-copy-of-a-list-in-python) of the list, while still removing items from the original list, as follows

```
lst=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for item in lst[:]: # note the `[:]`
    lst.remove(item)
print(lst)
# returns []
```

otherwise, you are iterating over a list that changes simultaneously, cf @Tibbles's explanation.