# How to remove palindromic words from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, palindrome

Here I have been trying to remove the palindromic words from the given string.
This is my code:

```
lis = list(text.split(" "))
newlis=[]
for i in range(len(lis)):
   if (lis[i] != lis[i][::-1]):
       newlis.append(lis[i])
print(newlis)
```

If the input is

```
Nair speaks malayalam
```

I get the output as

```
['Nair', 'speaks', 'Malayalam']
```

Why the palindromic words aren't removed?

Comment: `Malayalam` will not be identified as a palindrome unless you add code to ignore case.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a string is palindrome with `str(n) == str(n)[::-1]`

So you can create a function and filter the list with it as follows:

```
def is_palindrome(n):
  return str(n) == str(n)[::-1]

lis = [wrd for wrd in list(text.split(" ")) if not is_palindrome(wrd)]
```

Here's a working repl.it project:

https://replit.com/@HarunYlmaz/Palindrome#main.py

**UPDATE**

As @Passerby stated in the comment, you may need to ignore case. If so, you can use `lower()` method as well:

```
str(n).lower() == str(n).lower()[::-1]
```

Comment: The `str(n)` seems to be reduant - because the passing in arg. is already string?

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension or filter:

```
>>> [i for i in text.split() if i != i[::-1]]
['Nair', 'speaks']
```

---

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x != x[::-1], text.split()))
['Nair', 'speaks']
>>>
```

Or to ignore case:

```
>>> [i for i in text.split() if i.lower() != i[::-1].lower()]
['Nair', 'speaks']
```

---

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x.lower() != x[::-1].lower(), text.split()))
['Nair', 'speaks']
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is fine. May be, in the question you've typed "malayalam" but actually it is "Malayalam". Lower case "m" is not equal to upper case "M" so it doesn't remove it. If you don't want case sensitive, then use `.lower()` method. This will make all the letters small and then check for palindrome which makes it non case sensitive. If you want input from the user as well to make it dynamic, here's another method. Seperate the words using `split()` function. Check for every word whether it is palindrome. If yes, remove it from the list, else continue. After than, unpack your list. Your code:

```
x=input("Enter string")
y=list(x.split())
for i in y:
    if i.lower()==i[::-1].lower():
        y.remove(i)

print(*y)
```

Comment: It is bad form to [remove items from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974628/why-does-removing-items-from-list-while-iterating-over-it-skip-every-other-item). This code has a subtle bug. If the input is `"radar alla notapalindrome"`, then the output would be `"alla notapalindrome"`, where the palindrome "alla" **was not removed**.

Answer (score -1):

```
txt = "malayalam is my mother tongue"
splittedArray = txt.split()
for s in splittedArray:
    if( s == s[::-1]):
        splittedArray.remove(s)
print(' '.join(splittedArray))
```

Comment: It is bad form to [remove items from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974628/why-does-removing-items-from-list-while-iterating-over-it-skip-every-other-item). This code has a subtle bug. If `txt` is `"The malayalam radar alla are all palindromes"`, then the output would be `"The radar are all palindromes"`, where the palindrome "radar" **was not removed**.