# Path Sum II(Leetcode113)

Tags: python

```
class Solution:
    def searchPath(self,node,targetSum,path,result):
        if (not node.left) and (not node.right) and (targetSum==0):
            result.append(path)
        if (not node.left) and (not node.right) and (targetSum!=0):
            return 
        if node.left:
            path.append(node.left.val)
            self.searchPath(node.left,targetSum-node.left.val,path,result)
            path.pop()
        if node.right:
            path.append(node.right.val)
            self.searchPath(node.right,targetSum-node.right.val,path,result)
            path.pop()

        return result
```

The answer will be wrong.
But if I change
`result.append(path)` to `result.append(path[:])`
The answer will be correct.
What's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `path[:]` creates a [shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16270387/2442804) of `path`. Later mutating `path` in the following `if`s does no longer change the `path` copy that was appended to `result`.

Appending `path` directly and later appending something to `path` changes the `path` that is already appended to `result`, effectively changing what `result` contains.